# Refactor out long if-else block using a mapping of two columns from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium

I am building a chatbot using Selenium and it has two short answers by now. When user sends '/help' the bot sends 'You asked for help', when user sends '/more', bot sends 'You asked more'...

```html
def conversation():
    if last_msg() == '/help':
        msg = 'You asked help'
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        input_field.send_keys(msg)
    elif last_msg() =='/more':
        msg = 'You asked more'
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        input_field.send_keys(msg)
    else:
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        input_field.send_keys('Sorry, input not listed')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3M-N-").click()
```

How can i escalate this using pandas? Assuming i have an csv with 2 columns, one named 'msg' and the other 'reply'. I would like to add many rows to this csv, without needing to change the code.

```html
    msg    reply
0   /help  you_asked_for_help
1   /more  you_asked_for_more
```

df_with_reply = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users...')

**How can i make this:**

```html
        if last_msg() == '/help':
            msg = 'You asked help'
            input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
            input_field.send_keys(msg)
        elif last_msg() =='/more':
            msg = 'You asked more'
            input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
            input_field.send_keys(msg)
```

**Turn into this:**

```html
        if last_msg() == IS IN df COLUMN 'msg'
        RETURN ACCORDING TEXT FROM df COLUMN 'reply' as X 

        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        input_field.send_keys(X)
        
        else:
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        input_field.send_keys('Sorry, input not listed')
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: Instead of having to map ifs and elifs, i would like to browse the df for the input msg and reply according to its correct answer. I plan to add 150 rows to my DF with custom msgs and replys, it will be dificult if i need to add more 600 lines so the bot can have more 150 commands. Am i clear about the question?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear. In my head it made sense. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a default dictionary mapping messages to replies.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

d = defaultdict(lambda: 'Sorry, input not listed')  
d.update(df.set_index('msg')['reply'].to_dict())
```

Now `d` can be accessed inside your function:

```
def conversation():
    input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
    input_field.send_keys(d[last_msg()])

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3M-N-").click()
```

Comment: So first i should import my df reading the csv, then i create this default dictionary ? Sorry i never used this before.

Comment: @guialmachado yes, read your dataframe with the column names that you show in your question, then create the dict as I've shown above.

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to add an argument so if the user sends '/helpp' or '/help0' the code recognizes that there is '/help' in msg and uses it as the standard '/help'? If this is out of context with the question/answer i appologize and there is no need to reply.

Comment: @guialmachado it should be possible, you can use re.search to extract the message from the input string. If you have trouble you should open a new question.